# Excel VBA - Separate data by pattern by using Split Function

Tags: excel, vba, powerquery

I am working on a special filter to divide cell from column E24:E33 into separate cells in range F24:M33
There are pattern words by which I want to divide the data:
**amount: price: price2: status: min: opt: cat: code z:**

[image]

I have already tested several methods to solve this issue, but none gave me a proper results. Unfortunately I am not a VBA programmer on such a high level to write it on my own completely from scratch.
This is the code I have so far but still the data is not being correctly divided:

```
    Sub qtest()
Dim a As Variant, b As Variant
'a = SpecialSplit("asdf:asdf asds:ert ert qwe d:sdfg") 'THIS TEST DATA WORKS FINE
a = SpecialSplit("amount:3 pc.  price:2397  price2:0 EU  status:In use min:1 opt:3 cat: DESTACO   code z:") DOESN'T WORK FOR ONE CELL
'SpecialSplit = Sheets("T4").Range("E24" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row 'ALSO DOESN't WORK FOR ENTIRE RANGE
ActiveCell.Offset(0, 1).Resize(1, UBound(a) - LBound(a) + 1).value = a
End Sub

    
Function SpecialSplit(Compound As String) As Variant
Dim pos1 As Long, pos2 As Long
Dim firstSplit As Variant
Dim elmts As Integer
Dim elmt As Integer
Dim oneel As String

firstSplit = Split(Compound, ":")
For elmt = LBound(firstSplit) To UBound(firstSplit) - 1
    oneel = firstSplit(elmt + 1)
    pos1 = InStr(oneel, " ")
    pos2 = Len(oneel)
    While pos1 > 0 And pos1 < Len(oneel) - 1
        pos2 = pos1
        pos1 = InStr(pos2 + 1, oneel, " ")
    Wend
    firstSplit(elmt) = firstSplit(elmt) & ":" & Left(oneel, pos2 - 1)
    firstSplit(elmt + 1) = Right(oneel, Len(oneel) - pos2)
Next elmt
    
elmts = UBound(firstSplit) - LBound(firstSplit) ' one shorter
If elmts > 0 Then ReDim Preserve firstSplit(1 To elmts)

SpecialSplit = firstSplit

End Function

Sub SpecialSpread(FromCell As Range)
Dim splitSet As Variant
splitSet = SpecialSplit(FromCell(1).Text)
If UBound(splitSet) >= 0 Then
    FromCell(1).Offset(0, 1).Resize(1, UBound(splitSet) - LBound(splitSet) + 1).value = splitSet
End If
End Sub

Sub qtest()
Dim a As Variant, b As Variant
'a = SpecialSplit("asdf:asdf asds:ert ert qwe d:sdfg") 'BY THIS PATTERN CODE WORKS
a = SpecialSplit("amount:3 pc.  price:2397  price2:0 EU  status:In use min:1 opt:3 cat: DESTACO   code z:") ' BY THIS PATTERN CODE DOESN'T WORK
'SpecialSplit = Sheets("T4").Range("E2" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
ActiveCell.Offset(0, 1).Resize(1, UBound(a) - LBound(a) + 1).value = a
End Sub
```

Comment: Look at using 'Text to Columns' functionality https://spreadsheeto.com/text-to-columns/

Comment: You received many answers when asked your previous question. I posted two such answers showing how to make  functions to return an array and how to drop the arrays content in a row. Anyhow, that time you did not mention that the last category may have empty values... Please, test the code I supplied in my answer.

Comment: @Tragamor  And split on what separator?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this in Power Query (available in Windows Excel 2010+ and Office 365.

This relies on the pattern words always being present and always in the same order.
In PQ we can actually split on the pattern words, so that part is easy.

If you just wanted to have the pattern words as column headers, we could stop there.

But since you want to have the pattern words precede the value in each cell, we have to Unpivot the table; create a merged column of the `pattern word + : + value`, then re-pivot on the Attribute column

To use it:

- Select some cell in your Data Table
- `Data => Get&Transform => from Table/Range`
- When the PQ Editor opens: `Home => Advanced Editor`
- Make note of the Table **Name** in Line 2
- Paste the M Code below in place of what you see
- Change the Table name in line 2 back to what was generated originally.
- Read the comments and explore the `Applied Steps` to understand the algorithm

**M Code**

```
let
    Source = Excel.CurrentWorkbook(){[Name="Table7"]}[Content],
    #"Changed Type" = Table.TransformColumnTypes(Source,{{"Column1", type text}}),

//List to split on
codeList = {
    "amount:",
    "price:",
    "price2:",
    "status:",
    "min:",
    "opt:",
    "category:",
    "code z:"},

//strip off terminal colon (:) to create list of column headers
colNames = List.Transform(codeList, each Text.TrimEnd(_,":")),

//split on the code list, and name the new columns
split = Table.SplitColumn(#"Changed Type","Column1", 
    Splitter.SplitTextByEachDelimiter(codeList),List.Combine({{"Column1"},colNames})),

//remove the now empty column1
    #"Removed Columns" = Table.RemoveColumns(split,{"Column1"}),

//could stop here if didn't have to merge the column header with the value
    
//To prefix each measurement with pattern word
    #"Unpivoted Columns" = Table.UnpivotOtherColumns(#"Removed Columns", {}, "Attribute", "Value"),
    #"Duplicated Column" = Table.DuplicateColumn(#"Unpivoted Columns", "Attribute", "Attribute - Copy"),
    #"Merged Columns" = Table.CombineColumns(#"Duplicated Column",
        {"Attribute", "Value"},Combiner.CombineTextByDelimiter(":", QuoteStyle.None),"Merged"),

    rePivot = fnPivotAll(#"Merged Columns","Attribute - Copy","Merged")
    
in
    rePivot
```

### custom function

***enter as blank query***
***rename `fnPivotAll`***

```
//credit: Cam Wallace  https://www.dingbatdata.com/2018/03/08/non-aggregate-pivot-with-multiple-rows-in-powerquery/

(Source as table,
    ColToPivot as text,
    ColForValues as text)=> 

let
     PivotColNames = List.Buffer(List.Distinct(Table.Column(Source,ColToPivot))),
     #"Pivoted Column" = Table.Pivot(Source, PivotColNames, ColToPivot, ColForValues, each _),
 
    TableFromRecordOfLists = (rec as record, fieldnames as list) =>
    
    let
        PartialRecord = Record.SelectFields(rec,fieldnames),
        RecordToList = Record.ToList(PartialRecord),
        Table = Table.FromColumns(RecordToList,fieldnames)
    in
        Table,
 
    #"Added Custom" = Table.AddColumn(#"Pivoted Column", "Values", each TableFromRecordOfLists(_,PivotColNames)),
    #"Removed Other Columns" = Table.RemoveColumns(#"Added Custom",PivotColNames),
    #"Expanded Values" = Table.ExpandTableColumn(#"Removed Other Columns", "Values", PivotColNames)
in
    #"Expanded Values"
```

**Raw Data**
[image]

**Split Data**
[image]

**Alternative solution**
[image]

Answer (score 1):

Try the next function, please:

```
Function extractFrStr(strInit As String) As Variant
  Dim arrStr, arrFin, i As Long, k As Long
  Dim arr1, arr2, firstEl As String, secEl As String
  
  arrStr = Split(strInit, ":")      'split the string by ":" character
  ReDim arrFin(UBound(arrStr))      'ReDim the final array at the  same number of elements
  For i = 0 To UBound(arrStr) - 1   'iterate between the array elements (except the last)
        arr1 = Split(arrStr(i), " ")     'split the i element by space (" ")
        arr2 = Split(arrStr(i + 1), " ") 'split the i + 1 element by space (" ")
        If i = 0 Then                    'for the first array element:
             firstEl = arrStr(i)         'it receives the array elemen value
        Else                             'for the rest of array elements:
            'extract firstEl (category) like first arr1 element, except the case of 'code z' which is extracted in a different way
             firstEl = IIf(i = UBound(arrStr) - 1, arr1(UBound(arr1) - 1) & " " & arr1(UBound(arr1)), arr1(UBound(arr1)))
        End If
        'in order to remove array elements, the code transformes the one to be removed in "|||":
        'it could be anything, but "|||" is difficult to suppose that it will be the text of a real element...
        If arrStr(i + 1) <> "" Then arr2(UBound(arr2)) = "|||": If i = UBound(arrStr) - 2 Then arr2(UBound(arr2) - 1) = "|||"
        'extract the secEl (the value) by joining the array after removed firstEl:
        secEl = IIf(i = UBound(arrStr) - 1, arrStr(UBound(arrStr)), Join(Filter(arr2, "|||", False), " "))
        arrFin(k) = firstEl & ":" & secEl: k = k + 1 'create the processed element of the array to keep the result
  Next i

  extractFrStr = arrFin
End Function
```

And use it to process your range, in the next way:

```
Sub SplitCategories()
  Dim sh As Worksheet, c As Range, arr
  Set sh = ActiveSheet
    For Each c In sh.Range("E24:E33").cells
        arr = extractFrStr(Trim(c.value))
        c.Offset(0, 1).Resize(1, UBound(arr)).value = arr
    Next c
End Sub
```

Answer (score 1):

Well OK, that's mostly the code I gave you in a previous question/answer. In order to implement a split of cells in E24:E33, you just need to feed those cells to the `SpecialSpread` routine... all the `qtest` stuff is just testing routines.

So this adds a `SpreadZone` routine to act on that specific range:

```
Function SpecialSplit(Compound As String) As Variant
Dim pos1 As Long, pos2 As Long
Dim firstSplit As Variant
Dim elmts As Integer
Dim elmt As Integer
Dim oneel As String

firstSplit = Split(Compound, ":")
For elmt = LBound(firstSplit) To UBound(firstSplit) - 1
    oneel = firstSplit(elmt + 1)
    pos1 = InStr(oneel, " ")
    pos2 = Len(oneel)
    While pos1 > 0 And pos1 < Len(oneel) - 1
        pos2 = pos1
        pos1 = InStr(pos2 + 1, oneel, " ")
    Wend
    firstSplit(elmt) = firstSplit(elmt) & ":" & Left(oneel, pos2 - 1)
    firstSplit(elmt + 1) = Right(oneel, Len(oneel) - pos2)
Next elmt

elmts = UBound(firstSplit) - LBound(firstSplit) ' one shorter
If elmts > 0 Then
    oneel = firstSplit(UBound(firstSplit))
    ReDim Preserve firstSplit(1 To elmts)
    firstSplit(elmts) = firstSplit(elmts) & ":" & oneel
End If

SpecialSplit = firstSplit

End Function

Sub SpecialSpread(FromCell As Range)
Dim splitSet As Variant
splitSet = SpecialSplit(FromCell(1).Text)
If UBound(splitSet) >= 0 Then
    FromCell(1).Offset(0, 1).Resize(1, UBound(splitSet) - LBound(splitSet) + 1).value = splitSet
End If
End Sub

Sub SpreadZone()
Dim ACell As Range
For Each ACell In Range("E24:E33")
    Call SpecialSpread(ACell)
Next ACell
End Sub
```

Edit: tweaked `SpecialSplit` a little to improve last field & correct empty field handling